# Kotlin Android Retrofit model will null attributes

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I need to make some request to an API using retrofit for an Android App, and i'm getting a response with null serialiced attributes.

I'm getting the Response object from the dataclass but with null attributes.

This is the retrofit config class

```
class RetrofitConfig {
    companion object {
        var URL_API = "I cant share the api link"

        fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_API)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the interface client

```
interface LoginAPIClient {
    @GET("/RS_Usuarios")
    suspend fun getLoginByUserandPass (
        @Query("idUser") userId : String,
        @Query("clave") userPass : String
    ): Response<LoginResponse>
}
```

This is the response data class

```
data class LoginResponse (
    @SerializedName("id") var id : String,
    @SerializedName("nombre") var uname : String,
    @SerializedName("apellido") var ulastname : String,
    @SerializedName("acceso") var uaccess : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("admin") var uadmin : Boolean
)
```

The endpoint receives an idUser and clave (password) as parameters in the query. This is the response object structure with 200 http response code.

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "nombre": "string",
  "apellido": "string",
  "acceso": true,
  "admin": true
}
```

I'm calling the Get method in this login function

```
    fun login(email: String, password: String, activity: AppCompatActivity) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call = RetrofitConfig.getRetrofit().create(LoginAPIClient::class.java)
                .getLoginByUserandPass(email, password)

            if (call.isSuccessful) {
                val body = call.body()

                body?.let {
                    println(call.code())
                    println(body)

                    if (body.uaccess) {
                        println("User has access")
                    } else {
                        println("User hasn't access")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run the app and the login function, i get this with the prints

```
I/System.out: 200
I/System.out: LoginResponse(id=null, uname=null, ulastname=null, uaccess=false, uadmin=false)
I/System.out: User can't access
```

I'm getting the LoginResponse object from the dataclass but with null attributes.

Comment: remove Response from interface LoginAPIClient ,
just return LoginResponse

Comment: @Elsunhoty I tried changing the return value of the function in LoginApiClient from Response<LoginResponse>  to  LoginResponse but i got the same:  ```I/System.out: LoginResponse(id=null, uname=null, ulastname=null, uaccess=false, uadmin=false)```